# 2.8 Node Names Different

Tags: rendering

So I decided to download Blender 2.8 but the Node Editor has different node names, all the Youtube videos I watch have the 2.79 names and so do my friends. Is there any way to change it? ex. material output is just called output and what i presume is diffuse bsdf is called checker.

Comment: Diffuse BSDF is still called the same, Checker is a texture node. You can always check the official documentation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/index.html

Comment: When I search up Diffuse BSDF nothing shows up.

Comment: Think I found the problem, turns out the texture node editor is not the node editor I was looking for and the correct one is the Shader Editor